# JavaScript reading visualforce binded variables

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html, dynamic-binding, dom

I need some help understand how JavaScript and Visualforce interact.

I have a eventListener that works perfectly when the DOM is loaded:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
if ('{!bvs.Status__c}' != 'Completed') {
    document.getElementById("populatedChart").style.display = "none";
}
if ('{!bvs.Status__c}' == 'Completed') {
    document.getElementById("oldPullreportbutton").style.display = "none";
}
if ('{!bvs.CompanyName__c}'.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("blankComp").style.fontWeight="bold"; 
}
});
```

I also have some code that tells the div to reRender after a button click:

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!pullReport}" onclick="showCreditPull()" oncomplete="stopSpinner()" value="Pull Report"/>

function showCreditPull() {
    var panel = $('.spinBorder');
    var spinner = panel.find(".business-loading-icon");
    spinner.show();
}

function stopSpinner(){
  var panel = $('.spinBorder');
  var spinner = panel.find(".business-loading-icon");
  spinner.hide();  
  rerenderData();//this is an actionFunction that reRenders the div
  if ('{!bvs.Status__c}' != null){
      document.getElementById("oldPullreportbutton").style.display = "none";
  }
  else{
      $("#populatedChart").replaceWith( "<p>Error!</p>" ); 
  }
}
```

My question is- why does is `{!bvs.Status__c}` in `stopSpinner()` not recognized? No matter what the status is, it runs through and hides the `oldPullreportbutton`. It's acting like it doesn't recognize the binded  `{!bvs.Status__c}`. But it is able to be read with the eventListener.

UPDATE:
Code from inspect:

```
if(true){
    document.getElementById("oldPullreportbutton").style.display = "none";
    $("#populatedChart").replaceWith( "<p>Error!</p>" );
    console.log('got out 1');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'{!bvs.Status__c}'` is guaranteed to never be null, because even if Status is an empty string, your code effectively evaluates as:

```
if('' != null) {
```

Clearly, "empty string" is not the same as null, so this condition is always true.

Instead, consider using:

```
if({!ISBLANK(bvs.Status__c)}) {
```

Which will evaluate to this when the string is empty:

```
if(true) {
```

And will evaluate to this otherwise:

```
if(false) {
```

Comment: ({!ISBLANK(bvs.Status__c)}) is still coming back true no matter what the status is. When the page loads, it loads this conditional as 'true' and it does not change, even if I change the status__c value or not.

Comment: This leads me to believe that the JS is running on the initial page load and is saving the values ahead of time. Although it does not take any action until I call it. Does this sound correct?

Comment: @Olivia You have to "rerender" the script if you want the latest values. What you're trying to do is pretty fragile as is.

Comment: @ssfdcfox, I do rerender the script with `rerenderData();//this is an actionFunction that reRenders the div`. I have attempted `actionStatus` but this does not allow the correct end result either. Is there another way to make it less fragile?

Comment: @Olivia I generally recommend Using either pure Visualforce or pure JavaScript. Trying to mix the two isn't particularly nice in most cases. I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to do (I've seen a few of your questions), but you might consider either using a RemoteAction method and keep it all in JavaScript, or do the showing/hiding stuff using Visualforce's "rendered" and "reRender" attributes.

Comment: I have tried the RemoteAction as well with no success. My overall end goal is to click a button on a VFP, and post/get to an external server. While it is thinking I show a spinner. When the data is returned, the spinner shuts off, and I display the returned data on the page.  (either in place of the original button div or, I can hide the button div, and make a brand new table). The main criteria/obstacle I have faced is that I cannot have the page refresh so I must include ajax. Currently everything works except for the hiding/replacing of the div.

Comment: I am not convinced it is possible with ajax but I will keep digging into your suggestions.

Comment: @Olivia I've written code to this effect before. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: thank you that would be great. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48520/discussion-between-olivia-and-sfdcfox).